# Story about a woman who is surgically altered to a chimera

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, art

I am looking for the title of a short story where the protagonist meets a woman who has been surgically altered to manifest a figure in a painting - a sphinx.

The painting might have been 'The Sphinx' by Fernand Khnopff, 1896.

Comment: Do you remember when you read the story? And whether it was part of an anthology, standalone, etc?

Comment: In the setting of the story were such extreme body modifications common, or was the sphinx-woman a unique case?

Answer (score 9):

It might be [Greg Egan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Egan) story [The Caress](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40533) from Asimov's, January 1990. It can also be found in his collection Axiomatic.

> An investigation into the murder of a scientist leads to the discovery of her chimera creation Catherine, part leopard, part human.
> As Segel looks into it more he finds out about Andreas Lindquist, a strange artist. An attempt is also made on Catherine’s life, but he stops the assassin.
> However, deprimed at home he and his wife are drugged and taken into captivity, where Dan is operated on to fit Lindquist’s notion of art, to match Catherine, a la a painting. Lindquist apparently bred his son so that he could use brain manipulation and genetic techniques to make him similar in memory and attitude. So it is not sure which Lindquist actually took the pair.
> After several months they are again drugged, and returned home, where they attempt to rebuild their normal lives. Somewhat literally in Dan’s case.

Comment: This is what I would have suggested!